# Is there a way to change a string of numbers and words into a nested list, where the name are associated with their individual numbers in Python?

Tags: python, string, list, nested-lists

Example string:

```
ex_name_age = "Hannah 12, Daniel 98, Maya 30, Elizabeth 96"
```

Wanted format output:

```
[['Hannah', 12],
 ['Daniel', 98],
 ['Maya', 30],
 ['Elizabeth', 96]]
```

I tried using:

```
name_age_a = ex_name_age.split(", ")
name_age_a = [[val] for val in name_age_a]
print(name_age_a)
```

Which resulted in:

```
[['Hannah 12'],
 ['Daniel 98'],
 ['Maya 30'],
 ['Elizabeth 96']]
```

So I went quite wrong...

Does anyone know how to solve this, so each list will contain both `[["string", integer],...]` ?

Answer (score 1):

One option using a list comprehension:

```
[[name, int(age)]
  for x in ex_name_age.split(', ')
  for name, age in [x.split()]
]
```

Output:

```
[['Hannah', 12],
 ['Daniel', 98],
 ['Maya', 30],
 ['Elizabeth', 96]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you did correctly but second split is missing. You can try like this.

```
name_age_a = ex_name_age.split(", ")
name_age_a = [[val.split(' ')] for val in name_age_a]
print(name_age_a)
```

Comment: This won't perform the conversion to integer though ;)

Answer (score 0):

Each `val` in `name_age_a` is a string like `'Hannah 12'`. You need to split each of those strings on the empty space `' '`.

```py
ex_name_age = "Hannah 12, Daniel 98, Maya 30, Elizabeth 96"
name_age_a = ex_name_age.split(", ")
print(name_age_a) 
# ['Hannah 12', 'Daniel 98', 'Maya 30', 'Elizabeth 96']

out = []
for val in name_age_a:
    name, age = val.split(' ')  # unpack
    out.append([name, int(age)])
print(out)
# [['Hannah', 12], ['Daniel', 98], ['Maya', 30], ['Elizabeth', 96]]
```